# Efficient way doing comparizons and arithmetic in list with irregular dimensions , Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to find an efficient way to transform an array in the following way:

Each element will get transformed into either None, a real number, or a tuple/list/array of size 2 (contaning real numbers).

The transformation function im using is simple and just does number comparizons. So my first thought is to use np.where to make for fast comparizons. Now, if the transformation is a None or a real number, i have no problems.

But, when the transformation is a tuple/list/array, np.where gives me errors. This is ofc because numpy arrays demand regularity of dimensions. So now im forced to work with lists...

So my idea now is to, instead of tranforming the element into a tuple/list/Array of size 2, i transform it into a complex number. But then i have an Array of complex numbers containing mostly numbers with 0 imaginary part, (since most transformations will be None or real numbers). I cant afford this, memory speaking. (or?)

When i have the transformation list/Array/whatever, i will be doing sign operations and arithmetic btw its elements and comparizons again, thats why i would like to keep it being a numpy Array.

## Am I forced to work with lists in this scenario or would you do something else?

EDIT:
Im asked to give certaing examples of my transformation:

Input: an array contaning elements with values None or real numbers btw [0,360)

Transformation: (simplified):

None goes to None

element in [0,45) goes to 2 real numbers (left,right), say 2 random real numbers btw 0 and element.

element in [45,360) goes to 1 real number

what i do is for example:

```
arrayTransformed = np.where((array>=0) & (array<45), transform(array), array)
#this gives problems ofc
arrayTransformed = np.where((array>=45) & (array<=360), transform(array), arrayTransformed )
```

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of specific comparisons you want to make, as well as some examples of lists with which you would have this dilemma?

Comment: yes, i will add it on.

Comment: Can you give an example with the *specific* desired outcomes? 
`element in [0,45) goes to 2 real numbers (left,right)`
What 2 real numbers do you want your transformation to produce here?

Comment: An array with some `None` values has to be object dtype.  Such an array can also hold tuples.  Fast numeric operations are not possible on such an array.  `np.frompyfunc` is often the fastest way of applying a function to each element of such an array (with a 2x speedup compared to direct iteration).  Give us a sample array, and a function that works on one element of that array.

Comment: When you do `np.where(cond, A(), B())`, Python evaluates all 3 arguments before passing them to `where`.  If they differ in shape, `numpy` uses `broadcasting`.